# Do SpringBoot annotations like GetMapping use Spring AOP internally?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

A maybe dumb question from a Spring Boot beginner.

I'm reading materials about AOP, and feel like the processing of a lot of annotations (including `GetMapping` and `PostMapping`) fits natually with AOP - we have a common concern (say, all functions annotated with `GetMapping` be treated as HTTP GET method) that is distributed over many different classes.

So does Spring internally use AOP to implement its handlers for stuff like `GetMapping`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Spring does not use AOP in order to find the correct handler for the requested URI.

That's essentially the job of the **[DispatcherServlet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-servlet)**.

`@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, `@PutMapping`, `@PatchMapping`, `@DeleteMapping` are all shortcuts for their respectives `@RequestMapping` annotations.

The `DispatcherServlet` is a front controller that handles the incoming requests and delegates them to the correct handler.

When a request arrives, the `DispatcherServlet` uses `HandlerMapping`s and `HandlerAdapter`s from the `WebApplicationContext` to delegate the request to the appropriate handler. Of course it's a lot more complicated then just that and there's a lot of engineering going on.

The `DispatcherServlet` doesn't invoke the handler method directly, instead, the `HandlerAdapter` interface is used. Specifically, in the case of `@RequestMapping` annotations and it's shortcuts, the  [**RequestMappingHandlerAdapter**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) is used together with the [**RequestMappingHandlerMapping**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html).

The `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is used by the `DispatcherServlet` to obtain the handler object (when using `@RequestMapping` in a class instead of a method) and the handler method (when using `@RequestMapping` and it's shortcuts in a method). This class is responsible for creating the **[RequestMappingInfo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfo.html)** for each `@RequestMapping` annotated class or method, so, basically, it maps  the corresponding handlers to it's paths.

The `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is used to invoke the handler method through the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#invokeHandlerMethod` (see **[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html#invokeHandlerMethod-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod-)**)

So no, Spring doesn't use AOP in this case. It's a lot of intelligent mapping going on.